# what is the proper syntax for the following expression in swift 3?

Tags: error-handling, swift3

as you can guess, this is an issue regarding swift's whole API renovation. I've read the documentation extensively but can't seem to lay my finger on a proper workaround.

I am receiving the error

> Value of type 'Error' has no member 'userInfo'

on the following line:

```
else if let secondMessage = error?.userInfo["error"] as? String
```

of this block:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Images")
query.whereKey("Subject", equalTo: self.subjectName)
query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        // do something
    }else if let secondMessage = error?.userInfo["error"] as? String {
        // do something
    }
```

Any suggestions? feel's like I'm missing something painstakingly obvious... dev block i guess :(

Comment: Swift 3 changed the way error handling works and previous implicit casting to NSError now requires an explicit cast. Suggest trying (error as? NSError)?.userInfo.